# Debugging Android App Error

Tags: android-studio

After updating Gradle to later version from an old app project, when trying to debuge this error came out. Any idea how to solve it ? It's related to googlemap, as when the app launched and trying to enter a page that have map the app will be crashed. :(

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: my.sdi.android, PID: 22208
              java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord{183b711 22208:my.sdi.android/u0a88} (pid=22208, uid=10088) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1943)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
                  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4365)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
                  at my.sdi.android.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:84)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)


E/ACRA: ACRA caught a SecurityException for my.sdi.android
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord{183b711 22208:my.sdi.android/u0a88} (pid=22208, uid=10088) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1943)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4365)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
        at my.sdi.android.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:84)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: This is kind of a security exception. Check whether the necessary permissions are given or not

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same issue
if you already added permission to your manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`
use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`
It will bring up the phone dialer, the same way others applications behave (same user experience).